# Tauri JS API dialog and notification modules not doing anything, returning null

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, tauri

I am familiarizing myself with the [tauri](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri) framework currently by developing a small desktop app. Most of the tauri JS API modules I have been testing have worked so far, except for the `dialog` and `notification` modules. When any of the functions from the `dialog` module are tested, for example `open`, the promise immediately resolves with a `null` value, and nothing on the tauri end noticeably occurs (for example, when the `open` function is called, a file dialog should appear). I haven't altered the generated Rust files at all, and I am using a VueJS SPA on the frontend, which I have been running in a 64-bit Windows 10 environment. Additionally, the `tauri.conf.json` file has the correct permissions set for the use of these modules.

This is the code where I call the `dialog.open` function:

```
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { open as openDialog } from "@tauri-apps/api/dialog";

@Options({
  components: {
    ... some vue components ...
  },
})
export default class Freeze extends Vue {
  selectedFilepaths: string[] = [];

  async selectFile(){
    const pathName: string = await openDialog({
      defaultPath: ".",
      multiple: false
    }) as string;
    this.selectedFilepaths.push(pathName);
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the culprit was `defaultPath` field.

You have to provide a valid path there (or not use it at all), otherwise it will fail silently.